# how to make an if statement based on a list

Tags: python

so I have to make a rock paper scissors game in my class today and was wondering how to make an if statement based on a list's order than setup a loop for that
here is the code

```
def RockPaperScissorsFunction4(roundnumberforcurrentpairing, mychoices[], opponentchoices[]):
    import random
    first_random = random.randint(1, 3)
    # 1 = rock 2 = paper 3 = scissors
    if (roundnumberforcurrentpairing == 1 ):
        mynextmove = 1
    # mynextmove = opponentchoices[roundnumberforcurrentpairing - 2]
    if roundnumberforcurrentpairing < 3:
        mynextmove = 1 
    if opponentchoices[1, 3, 3, 3,]:
        
    if opponentchoices[2, 3, 3, 3,]:
        
    if opponentchoices[3, 3, 3, 3,]:
```

Comment: If I understand the question properly, I think you can do `if opponentchoices[:4] == [1,3,3,3]:` etc.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is that you want to For loop with Array child ?
If you want opporentchoice [1,3,3,3] to came out as
1
3
3
3
then compare with first_random

here example :

```
opponentchoices = [1,3,3,3]
for x in opponentchoices:
   first_random = random.randint(1, 3)
   if(first_random > x):
       print("You win")
   else:
       print("Opporent win")
```

Anyway you need to us more detail in this question

***update***

```
import random

def RockPaperScissorsFunction4(totalround, MyChoices, opponentchoices):
    RoundCount = 2
    MaxRound = len(opponentchoices)     # We do this because we Don't need Max round more than opponent's choice

    if(totalround > MaxRound):          # if total round is more than choice  Set total round = length of opponent's Array
        totalround = MaxRound 
        print("Set totalround = ",totalround)

    for opponent_answer in opponentchoices:
        if RoundCount >= totalround:
            break
        if opponent_answer > opponent_answer:
            print("opponent win!")
        else : 
            print("Player win!")

        RoundCount = RoundCount + 1

player_answer = random.randint(1, 3)
opponent_array = [1, 3, 3, 3]
RockPaperScissorsFunction4(5,player_answer,opponent_array)

player_answer = random.randint(1, 3)
opponent_array = [2, 3, 3, 3]
RockPaperScissorsFunction4(5,player_answer,opponent_array)

player_answer = random.randint(1, 3)
opponent_array = [3, 3, 3, 3]
RockPaperScissorsFunction4(5,player_answer,opponent_array)
```